# is there any idiom to refer to information that comes from the 1st line of battle?

Tags: idiom-requests

Would "news from the trenches" be acceptable and understood?

I am not sure if it is proper English or a direct translation from the Spanish idiom "desde las trincheras".

Comment: There isn't an exact equivalent English idiom that I'm aware of. I would think this would be understood. Perhaps 'news from the Front'?

Comment: There's nothing especially wrong with "news from the trenches" it just sounds dated. Trench warfare drums up images of World War 1 for me. Edit: also it would definitely be used idiomatically and never to describe news literally about war. Too cliche.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "first line of battle" is known as the *front*:

> **front**<sup>2</sup>
>
> The foremost line or part of an armed force; the furthest position that an army has reached and where the enemy is or may be engaged:
>   *his regiment was immediately sent to the front*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/front#front__13)

> [*All Quiet on the Western Front*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Quiet_on_the_Western_Front)

So for news from the first line of battle, *News from the Front* may be appropriate, if it's clear that it refers to troops' news. Otherwise *front,* even capitalised, may be misinterpreted as a simple preposition. If such a misinterpretation is a risk, then to use *trenches* as you suggest, or *Trenches,* would definitely work.

You might also consider *Dispatches from the Front:* military news is relayed as a  *dispatch*.

> **dispatch**<sup>2</sup>
>
> An official report on state or military affairs:
>   *in his battle dispatch he described the gunner’s bravery*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispatch#dispatch__14)

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression **news from the front** , suggesting a source of news based directly where significant things are taking place, may fit your context.

[Front](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/front) : (from TFD)

> - A field of activity: the economic front.

As in:

- News from the business front
- News from the political front.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=news%20from%20the%20front%2Cnews%20front%20the%20business%20front&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnews%20from%20the%20front%3B%2Cc0):  news from the front.